# Object assessible outside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have two jQuery plugins:
The first one:

```
;(function($){

    function CbUploader(element,options){
        widget=this;
        .....
    }
    $.fn.cbUploader = function(options){
        new CbUploader(this,options);
        return this;
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

And the second one:

```
;(function($){

    function CbGallery(element,options){
        widget=this;
        $('body').on('click',".thumbnail-upload",function(){
             console.log(widget)
        });
    $.fn.cbGallery = function(options){
        new CbGallery(this,options);
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

When I click on .thumbnail-upload div console.log returns CbUploader object instead CbGallery. Why plugin scope isolation doesn't work in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't register `widget` variable globally, use a local variable with `var`. Like you did, you use `window.widget = this` witch override each other then.

```
function CbGallery(element, options) {
    var widget = this;

    $('body').on('click', '.thumbnail-upload', function() {
        console.log(widget);
    });
}
```

And do the same in the `CbUploader` function too.